# What documentation should be created in Agile?

Tags: architecture, documentation, agile, software-design

I'm more asking about technical documents such as ER Diagrams , use case diagrams and other UML diagrams. I know Agile is a big word and there are tons of material out there with dozens of different implementations and also there are lot of debates about what it actually is.

However, what I need to know is, from a practical point of view, what documents are created prior and throughout the development process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't agree fully with Daniel

Ofc I can't argue with manifesto but diagrams, documentation are absolutly ok in my opinion.

1. a story is a description. but for programmers it may be too little. The story gives info what will happen when, and this should be converted to diagrams, documentation
2. software should be well documented. Diagrams and everything created during the sprints will create the final documentation of the project for future team members cause let be serious, the team members can change more often than we want to

the proper question is who should create it. As for me this is on the development team side. They should create it while developing each items from product backlog. They should ask question to product owner

Comment: What are these documents? How far we should go? Can you please suggest me few types?

Comment: @RandikaWijekoon in my opinion documents in most cases are depending on the project. BUT there is a minimum that will always be handy. As project owner I would like to constantly develop requirements specification that will be built based on stories, from development team I would like to receive technical specification, basic diagrams etc. The MINIMUM stuff that will be very handy on each project phase and will be very helpfull for whole scrum team

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use as much auto generated documentation as possible. There are plenty of tools that can reverse engineer UML and ER diagrams based on your code. Document your API by auto generated Javadoc and so on. This removes much of the documentation workload.

But it's important to include the documentation work into your workflow, because few things are worse than out of date documentation, which contradicts with the production code. So you could for example add "Update documentation" to your *Definition of Done*.

BDD is another useful tool, which helps you to document/define the requirements and functionality of your software and on the other optimizes your code quality once you implement the tests to verify the defined scenarios.

Comment: Can you suggest few useful tool for  Visual Studio?

Comment: AFAIK Visual Studio has these tools built-in (at least the Ultimate version), but I'm not a Visual Studio guy, so I'dont know for certain.

Comment: Enterprise Architect by Sparx Systems has Visual Studio integration for document generation from code (http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html).  @kiview, I like your suggestion of adding "Update Documentation" to the Definition of Doneness for user stories.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Agile manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/):

"Working software over comprehensive documentation"

So really no documentation is required for the Agile process, in contrast to a typical Waterfall process where you *need* to create documentation (requirements, design, traceability, verification/validation, etc.) as part of the process.

Well, maybe that's a gross over-simplification.  For instance in Scrum, you do have a [Product Backlog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28software_development%29#Product_backlog) which is a collection of user stories that will be developed over a series of sprints.  It could be argued that this is documentation.

I think the spirit of the rule is that documentation is not a deliverable in the Agile process.  It should not interfere with customer collaboration.  So by all means, draw an ER diagram with the customer during a meeting if it helps both sides communicate.  In Agile, it has no real merit beyond that.

Comment: Don't we at least draw an ER?